# True / False about a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A= \begin {pmatrix} x & y \\ -y & x \end {pmatrix}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$.

1) For any $n \ge 1$, $$A^n= \begin {pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin \theta \\  -\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end {pmatrix}$$ where $x=\cos(\theta/n)$ and $y=\sin(\theta/n)$.

2) tr(A) $\neq 0$

3) $A^t=A^{-1}$

4) $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix over $\mathbb{C}$.

I got only second is false, and rest are true. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the third should be true as well; the usual determinant formula divides by $1$, exchanges $\cos(\theta)$ with itself, and then switches the signs on the off-diagonal, which amounts to exchanging $\sin(\theta)$ and $-\sin(\theta)$. (Alternately you can note that the columns are orthonormal.)

Comment: If $x = 0$ and $y = 1$, then $\mathrm{tr}(A) = ?$

Comment: Oh, darn. I read "only the third is false" and thought that the third was the "trace" one, not the transpose-and-inverse one. My apologies. The correct statement is that only the second is false. Thanks, Ian and David K, for setting me straight.

Comment: Yeah I also wanted to write second is false, did the same mistake in mind. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why will $A$ be diagonalizable?

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^2-2\lambda+1$  Compute the discriminant $D=4(x^2-1)$ It is not always $>0$ say $x=1or-1$ and hence the minimal polynomial does not split into distinct linear factors always

3 is  correct and 2 is false